# Is the Gargoyle's Tail Sweep virtually ineffective against players who are less than or equal to 1 node away?

Tags: dark-souls

The gargoyle's tail sweep turns to the closest player and moves 1 step toward them, effectively giving the player the option to get pushed into the space just vacated by the gargoyle (behind it). This not only makes the attack miss but also puts the player in a position to attack its weak spot. Is this simply a very weak behavior or am I misplaying the push (or other) dynamics?

Answer (score 3):

When bosses push players off their node, they must stay within the current arc relative to the boss (unlike when normal enemies push players). This prevents players from hopping behind a boss or to a convenient arc. Only dodging allows jumping to different arcs.